# Rails Template File - looping through columns in a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iteration, erb

I have a table with fields named day1, day2 and so on till day23.

I have the data in a variable named forecast and am trying to print the values in the template file as shown below:

```
<td><% forecast.day1 %></td>
```

Can I do the above in a loop for days 1 till 23? Please help!

Also, I would like to check if the value of a day is null and display it only if it is not null. Can I use .present for this? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work:

```
<% (1..23).each do |n| %>
  <td><%= forecast.public_send("day#{n}") %></td>
<% end %>
```

So, you iterate through a range of 1 to 23, sending the method `day#{n}` to the `forecast` for each number, using [`public_send`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/public_send).

Regarding the second part of your question, to only display the `td` if the element is present, you can use:

```
<% (1..23).each do |n| %>
  <% if (forecast_for_day = forecast.public_send("day#{n}")).present? %>
    <td><%= forecast_for_day %></td>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This assigns the result to a local variable during the check and is used to display the result if present - saves having to call the method twice.

Hope that helps - let me know if you've any questions.

Comment: Welcome - happy to help :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<%= (1..23).each do |day_num| %>
  <% if forecast.send("day#{day_num}").present? %>
    <td><% forecast.send("day#{day_num}") %></td>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If you have the day number in any variable then iterate through it instead of (1..23)

Comment: That's an exact copy of my answer, though with less detail and explanation. Do we need the duplication?